# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'trust server certificate'

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, production, webdeploy

I have deploy a ASP.Net Core MVC Web Application in IIS using web deploy, certain page like Homepage, About us is working fine, but page like a listing page which will getting data from sql database is getting this error. For example page that getting error are Login page, after trying to login into the website will get this error message. Then when I want to access the listing page also will get this error.

The error says, "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'trust server certificate'.
Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary<string, string> parsetable, string connectionString, bool buildChain, Dictionary<string, string> synonyms, bool firstKey)"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEKrN.png)

I've trying some solution to fix the error but still the same.
What I've try is:

1. I try changing the connection string to use the "encrypt" option instead of "Trust Server Certificate"

   `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;encrypt=true;`

Comment: And into your connection string TrustServerCertificate=Yes and Persist Security Info=True;

Comment: ```Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True;Trust Server Certificate=Yes;``` -> I have added this and getting this error message on that page : " ```This page isn’t working my website is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500``` "

Comment: Trust Server Certificate=True changed to TrustServerCertificate=True

Comment: I have a localdb connection like `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=xxx;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true` and I didn't see empty between the parameter name. Could you pls take a try for it? By the way, I searched for the error messsage, and I [found this](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/87158/keyword-not-supported-trust-server-certificate) which is similar to your issue.

Comment: The issue is solved. I try to point IIS path on the application folder then it's working fine and can view the data from database. Thank you for your help @Tiny Wang

Comment: thank you for informing us that your issue is solved : )

Answer (score 0):

Issue may be caused when an https page was loaded, but insecure elements, http elements, were being requested. You may be able to fix your issue by going to your Visual Studio to uncheck 'trust server certificate' as follows:

1. Step one - open your visual studio and load the project or solution with the issue
2. Step two - Click publish from solution explorer like you want to publish to the hosting server:
   [Start publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CSCW.png)
3. Step three - On the publish page, select 'More actions' drop down button and click edit
   [Select 'More actions' button and click 'edit'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci1GL.png)
4. Step four - A dialog box appears, Publish, click the three ... on the far right of the 'Data source' connection strings
   [Click the horizontal three ... menu far right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p5oU.png)
5. Step five - another dialog appears, the Destination Connection String
   [On the Destination Connection String, uncheck 'Trust Server Certificate'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50XT4.png)
6. Step six - click ok and save the new setting.
7. Step seven - publish your application and login to use the application. That should fix it.